# IKEv2 Certificate Based Network Signon

Tags: windows, vpn, routing, certificate, windows-server-2016

Hello I have a working IKEV2 certificate based Authenticated VPN. I was trying to get my network sign on working but I had no luck. When I had a PPTP VPN and had "Allow other people to use this connection" checked it then showed the network sign on icons at windows logon.

But with the IKEV2 Cert based when I have that checked it doesn't show the network sign on option. Does IKEV2 Certificate based not support Network sign on?

If it doesn't how do you run the AD Logon Script if they don't use Network Sign on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User personal certificates are stored encrypted with the user's login password, so naturally it is impossible to use them before you've logged in.

You will need to use IKEv2 *machine* certificate authentication ([device tunnel](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-access/vpn/vpn-device-tunnel-config)). (AFAIK, Windows can automatically switch to per-user VPN after logging in.)